# jQCloud does not show properly in Bootstrap Modal (not with angular, only jquery)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, word-cloud

I am using the JQCloud (WordCloud) plugin. Not the AngularJS-Version. It works fine. But, it doesn't show properly in a Bootstrap Modal.

```
$('#top-nav-bar').on('click', function() {
    $('#wordcloud').jQCloud('update', words); 
});

$('#wordcloud').jQCloud(words, {
    classPattern: null,
    fontSize: { from:  0.1, to: 0.02 }
});
```

The Spans all get the styles: `font-size: 0; left:0px; top;0px;`

Comment: welcome to SO, provide error you facing

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].